# Saving a nested collection with MVC 3, EF 4.1, DbContext, and AutoMapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework-4.1, automapper

I am having difficulty getting a nested collection (Tags in my case) to commit back to the database after being passed into my controller.  I am using EF 4.1 with the DbContext API, MVC 3, and Automapper.

My Models:

```
Partial Public Class Proposal
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Memo As String
    Public Property EntryDate As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Overridable Property CategoryTags As ICollection(Of CategoryTag) = New HashSet(Of CategoryTag)

End Class

Public Class ProposalViewModel

    Public Property Id As Integer
    <DataType(DataType.MultilineText)>
    Public Property Memo As String
    <DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, DataFormatString:="{0:d}")>
    Public Property EntryDate As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Overridable Property CategoryTags As ICollection(Of CategoryTag) = New HashSet(Of CategoryTag)
End Class
```

My view uses the code from the following post to add tags:  http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/2995732471/nested-collection-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3.  Essentially the tags are created by adding INPUT elements with their name attribute set to "CategoryTag[0].Id", "CategoryTag[1].Id" etc... and the value of those inputs are valid Ids for Tags in my database

Lastly, my POST code:

```
<HttpPost()>
Public Function Edit(ByVal pvm As ProposalViewModel) As ActionResult

    Dim p As New Proposal

    p = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(Of ProposalViewModel, Proposal)(pvm)

    If (ModelState.IsValid) Then
        db.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    Else
        Return View(pvm)
    End If

End Function
```

The pvm object is returned to my controller with the values set as I would want them to be.  If I add two tags in run-time, then it has two CategoryTag objects in it's collection with the appropriate IDs.  The problem is that on my call to SaveChanges, the corresponding records are not created in my many-to-many relation table (ProposalCategoryTag in this case).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I did not find anything on this, and have resorted to doing it manually like below.  I dislike this method, but it works.

```
<HttpPost()>
Public Function Edit(ByVal pvm As ProposalViewModel) As ActionResult

    Dim p As New Proposal
    Dim tempTag As CategoryTag

    p = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(Of ProposalViewModel, Proposal)(pvm)

    If (ModelState.IsValid) Then

        db.Proposals.Attach(p)
        db.Entry(p).Collection("CategoryTags").Load()

        For Each ct As CategoryTag In pvm.Tags

            tempTag = db.CategoryTags.Find(ct.Id)

            If tempTag Is Nothing Then
                Continue For
            End If

            If p.CategoryTags.Contains(tempTag) Then
                Continue For
            End If

            p.CategoryTags.Add(tempTag)
        Next

        db.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    Else

        Return View(pvm)

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: It might be helpful to leave the question open longer than 3 days if you want a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I did not find anything on this, and have resorted to doing it manually like below. I dislike this method, but it works.

```
    <HttpPost()>
    Public Function Edit(ByVal pvm As ProposalViewModel) As ActionResult

        Dim p As New Proposal
        Dim tempTag As CategoryTag

        p = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(Of ProposalViewModel, Proposal)(pvm)

        If (ModelState.IsValid) Then

            db.Proposals.Attach(p)
            db.Entry(p).Collection("CategoryTags").Load()

            For Each ct As CategoryTag In pvm.Tags

                tempTag = db.CategoryTags.Find(ct.Id)

                If tempTag Is Nothing Then
                    Continue For
                End If

                If p.CategoryTags.Contains(tempTag) Then
                    Continue For
                End If

                p.CategoryTags.Add(tempTag)
            Next

            db.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        Else


            Return View(pvm)

        End If

    End Function
```